# Hurwitz's theorem for Diophantine approximation

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

Hurwitz's Theorem in Number Theory states that for every irrational number $\xi$, there are infinitely many relatively prime natural numbers $(p,q)$ satisfying the equation:
$$ | \xi−\frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2} $$

I'm interested in unilateral approximations to $\xi.$ Specifically, letting

$$ L = \left\{(p,q): \; p \text{ and } q \text{ are relatively prime positive integers such that } \frac{p}{q} < \xi \text{ and } \left|\xi - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2} \right\} $$

and

$$ U = \left\{(p,q): \; p \text{ and } q \text{ are relatively prime positive integers such that } \frac{p}{q} > \xi \text{ and } \left|\xi - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}q^2} \right\}, $$

then for each irrational $\xi$ we can conclude that AT LEAST ONE of the sets $L$ and $U$ is infinite. Do we know whether, for each irrational $\xi,$ BOTH of the sets are infinite? If not, then do we at least know whether, for each irrational $\xi,$ BOTH of the sets are not empty?

Comment: any $p>\xi$, and $q=1$?

Comment: The simple continued fraction gives approximations alternating too big and too small , hence there are in fact inifnite many fractions (and more important : arbitary good fractions both from above and from below) doing the job.

Comment: (I retracted my vote to close because I just understood what op meant; still I think the question should be reformulated to be clearer)

Comment: dd689 -- I've clarified what I believe is your question. Feel free to revert back to your original question, or revise the original differently, if what I've done is not what you are asking or there is something else not appropriate about what I've done. @Peter -- Your comment seems to be an answer to my revised version of the question, although perhaps a reference (even if only to a section of Wikipedia) would be helpful.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro In the case that the fractions must satisfy the Hurwitz inequality, I am not sure. Your version makes much more sense than asking for fractions just larger than some given irrational number (there are trivially infinite many) and also for infinite many fractions arbitary close to the given irrational number (which is still an elementary result).

Comment: It might be that if all the even partial quotients (in the continued fraction for $\xi$) are small, while all the odd partial quotients are big, then all the Hurwitz-good approximations will be on the same side of $\xi$.

Comment: Some literature that may be relevant:  L.C. Eggan, I. Niven: A remark on one–sided approximation, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 12 (1961), 538–540;  R.M. Robinson: Unsymmetrical approximation of irrational numbers, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 53
(1947), 351–361; B. Segre: Lattice points in infinite domains, and asymmetric Diophantine approximations, Duke Math. J. 12 (1945), 337–365

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks for reformulating. That's indeed what I meant.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted yesterday, dd689?

Comment: Earth to dd689 – come in, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 1 of the Eggan & Niven paper mentioned in the comments says,

For any $c>1$ there are uncountably many irrationals $\xi$ for which $$0<{a\over b}-\xi<{1\over cb^2}$$ has no rational solutions $a/b$. Analogously, for any $c>1$ there are uncountably many irrationals $\xi$ for which $0<\xi-(a/b)<1/(cb^2)$ has no rational solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer!